# Changing font to a title inside a box

Tags: color, tcolorbox

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[x11names,svgnames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{XCharter}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\definecolor{recyclecolor}{named}{Goldenrod1}

\makeatletter

\tcbset{%
  decoration downshift/.store in={\decoration@downshift},
  decoration radius/.store in={\decoration@radius},
  decoration recycle radius/.store in={\decoration@recyclecircleradius},
  decoration dot radius/.store in={\decoration@dotradius},
  decoration content/.store in={\decoration@content},
  decoration colour/.store in={\decoration@colour},
}

\tcbset{recyclebox/.style={decoration radius=0.5cm,decoration downshift=-0.5cm}}

\tcbset{learnthisbox/.style={%
    decoration radius=0.5cm,
    decoration downshift=-0.5cm,
    decoration content={\bclampe},
    decoration colour=blue}
}

\newtcolorbox{learnthis}[2][]{%
  learnthisbox,
  breakable,
  enhanced jigsaw,
  leftrule=1.5pt,
  fonttitle={\bfseries\large},
  title={\MakeUppercase{Learn This!}},
  attach title to upper={{~\bfseries\large #2} \par},
  #1,
  interior style={left color=tcbcol@back, right color=tcbcol@back,middle color=tcbcol@back!03},
  underlay unbroken and first={%
    \draw[tcbcol@frame,line width=\kvtcb@left@rule,fill=tcbcol@back] ($(frame.north west) + (\kvtcb@left@rule-0.03pt,\decoration@downshift)$) arc [start angle=90.0,end angle=270.0,radius=\decoration@radius] node[midway,right] (dottedcircle) {\decoration@content};
  },
  % Something to be set after #1 has been red!
  colframe=\decoration@colour,
  colback=\decoration@colour!10,
  coltitle={tcbcol@frame},
}

\makeatother




\begin{document}

\begin{learnthis}[decoration content={\bccrayon}]{Past Tense}
\blindtext
\end{learnthis}


\end{document}
```

This code displays:

[image]

I want the text **LEARN THIS!** to be displayed with another font (also bold), for example I tried to put `title={\MakeUppercase{\sf Learn This!}}` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Just add `\sffamily` to the font keys, and use a sans font which has a bold variant:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[x11names,svgnames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{XCharter}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\definecolor{recyclecolor}{named}{Goldenrod1}

\makeatletter

\tcbset{%
  decoration downshift/.store in={\decoration@downshift},
  decoration radius/.store in={\decoration@radius},
  decoration recycle radius/.store in={\decoration@recyclecircleradius},
  decoration dot radius/.store in={\decoration@dotradius},
  decoration content/.store in={\decoration@content},
  decoration colour/.store in={\decoration@colour},
}

\tcbset{recyclebox/.style={decoration radius=0.5cm,decoration downshift=-0.5cm}}

\tcbset{learnthisbox/.style={%
    decoration radius=0.5cm,
    decoration downshift=-0.5cm,
    decoration content={\bclampe},
    decoration colour=blue}
}

\newtcolorbox{learnthis}[2][]{%
  learnthisbox,
  breakable,
  enhanced jigsaw,
  leftrule=1.5pt,
  fonttitle={\sffamily\selectfont\bfseries\large},
  title={\MakeUppercase{Learn This!}},
  attach title to upper={{~\sffamily\bfseries\large #2} \par},
  #1,
  interior style={left color=tcbcol@back, right color=tcbcol@back,middle color=tcbcol@back!03},
  underlay unbroken and first={%
    \draw[tcbcol@frame,line width=\kvtcb@left@rule,fill=tcbcol@back] ($(frame.north west) + (\kvtcb@left@rule-0.03pt,\decoration@downshift)$) arc [start angle=90.0,end angle=270.0,radius=\decoration@radius] node[midway,right] (dottedcircle) {\decoration@content};
  },
  % Something to be set after #1 has been red!
  colframe=\decoration@colour,
  colback=\decoration@colour!10,
  coltitle={tcbcol@frame},
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{learnthis}[decoration content={\bccrayon}]{Past Tense}
\blindtext
\end{learnthis}

\end{document}
```

[image]